# Stop or disable the number of retries, of an API REST WSO2 ESB

Tags: api, wso2-esb

I have performed a REST API where I obtain information in XML format, where it is transformed by means of the datamapper artifact and later inserted into the database, the error occurs when the volume of transactions is very high and a second attempt of the API occurs, but the first one has been saved correctly therefore in the second API attempt causes a duplicity, Is there a way to control that does not make the retry, either by property or from configuration of some file?.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/context/test" name="Save_transaction" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource faultSequence="ErrorSequense" methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            
       <property expression="$body/Content/filename" name="filename" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    <log level="custom" separator="|">
                        <property expression="get-property('filename')" name="In API"/>
                    </log>
                    <sequence key="Sequence_Mapper"/>
                                
                    <log level="custom" separator="|">
                        <property expression="get-property('filename')" name="EndMaper"/>
                    </log>
                    <sequence key="Save_transaction"/>
                    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                        <format>{"response":{"code":"00","message":"success"}}</format>
                        <args/>
                    </payloadFactory>
                    <property name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
                    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
                    <log level="full" separator="|">
                        <property expression="get-property('operation')" name="operation"/>
                        <property name="step" value="response"/>
                    </log>               
            <respond description="End Transaction"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

```
    <sequence name="Save_transaction" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <property expression="$body/Content/Producname" name="transactionID" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property expression="$body/Content/Date" name="startOID" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property expression="$body/Content/ProductNUmber" name="transactionNumber" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property expression="$body/Content/Description" name="objectOID" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <transaction action="new"/>
    <dbreport>
            <connection>
                <pool>
                    <dsName>ipe</dsName>
                </pool>
            </connection>
            <statement>
                <sql><![CDATA[insert into cnwx_transaction (Name, date, number, description) values(?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number=? ]]></sql>
                <parameter expression="get-property('Producname')" type="CHAR"/>
                <parameter expression="get-property('Date')" type="CHAR"/>
                <parameter expression="get-property('ProductNUmber')" type="CHAR"/>
                <parameter expression="get-property('Description')" type="CHAR"/>
                <parameter expression="get-property('ProductNUmber')" type="CHAR"/>
            </statement>
        </dbreport>
    <transaction action="commit"/>
    </sequence>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] to translate your question title to English.